# Error: Expected 'insert' to be string, but got primitive.D instead - MongoDB Atlas, Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm encountering an issue while trying to perform an insertMany operation in MongoDB Atlas using Mongoose. The error message I'm receiving is:

```
MongoBulkWriteError: Expected 'insert' to be string, but got primitive.D instead.
```

I've already tried disabling retryable writes by setting retryWrites to false in the connection options. However, the issue persists. Here's a simplified version of the relevant code

```
 // Mongoose connection options
const mongooseOptions = {
   retryWrites: false,
};
mongoose.connect(mongoURI, mongooseOptions);
```

Take a look at the endpoint

```
router.post('/insertMany', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        console.log(req.body);
        const category = await Category.insertMany(req.body.list);
        res.json(category);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        res.status(400).json({ error: error.message });
    }
});
```

Tried this

```
router.post('/insertMany', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        console.log(req.body);
        let list = req.body.list.map(cat => Category(cat))
        const category = await Category.insertMany(list);
        res.json(category);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        res.status(400).json({ error: error.message });
    }
});
```

Reqeust is sent through Postman

```
{
    "list": [
        {
            "name": "Test Category",
            "description": "Test category Desc"
        }
    ]
}
```

Error log

```
Incoming POST request to /category/insertMany
{
  list: [ { name: 'Test Category', description: 'Test category Desc' } ]
}
MongoBulkWriteError: Expected 'insert' to be string, but got primitive.D instead. Doc = [{insert [{collection category}]} {documents [[{name Test Category} {active true} {description Test category Desc} {_id ObjectID("65e19ac0e6f006f0730df049")} {__v 0}]]} {ordered true} {writeConcern [{w majority}]} {lsid [{id {4 [20 207 50 38 60 101 78 182 181 103 131 17 48 167 185 124]}}]} {$clusterTime [{clusterTime {1709283559 1}} {signature [{hash {0 [143 10 169 77 44 6 244 27 189 31 40 244 125 245 89 91 153 147 30 152]}} {keyId 7285440633500598274}]}]} {$db desejo}]
    at resultHandler (/Users/jayedumindu/Dev/Desejo-Ecommerce/Backend/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/bulk/common.js:294:29)
    at /Users/jayedumindu/Dev/Desejo-Ecommerce/Backend/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:274:66
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  ok: 0,
  code: 8000,
  codeName: 'AtlasError',
  writeErrors: [],
  result: BulkWriteResult {
    insertedCount: 0,
    matchedCount: 0,
    modifiedCount: 0,
    deletedCount: 0,
    upsertedCount: 0,
    upsertedIds: {},
    insertedIds: { '0': new ObjectId('65e19ac0e6f006f0730df049') }
  },
  insertedDocs: [
    {
      name: 'Test Category',
      active: true,
      description: 'Test category Desc',
      _id: new ObjectId('65e19ac0e6f006f0730df049'),
      __v: 0
    }
  ],
  [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(0) {}
}
```

Model ‍

```
    // models/Category.js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const categorySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: { type: String, unique: true },
    active: { type: Boolean, default: true }, // Added for tracking the active status
    description: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Category', categorySchema, { collection: 'category' });
```

Comment: What was the error when you did it this way `const category = await Category.insertMany(req.body.list);`?

Comment: @jQueeny I have mentioned that in the error log above  After that tried the other way which also ran into the same error

Comment: Do you get the same error if you do `const category = await Category.create([...req.body.list]);`?

Comment: @jQueeny Yes the same error occures!

Answer (score 0):

Removed the optional parameter

```
 module.exports = mongoose.model('Category', categorySchema, { collection: 'category' });
```

to

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('Category', categorySchema);
```

this worked! But how to tell Atlas to create the collection with the user given name?

Comment: `module.exports = mongoose.model('Category', categorySchema, 'customCollectionName');`. The third parameter needs to be a string.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).